# How to force reset on MMC/SD card

Tags: linux-kernel, reset, boot

### Background:

I have an embedded system (I CANNOT change hardware) with a self-built Linux system (I have complete control over software).

This system has several (3-wire, 3.3V) serial lines and I have no control over what is connected where (I can find out *after* boot).

### Problem:

If some external apparatus is connected to serial line, "mark" on RX line(s) (which I cannot prevent, in general), directly connected to microcontroller (MT7628AN, if it matters) is enough to give some power to system.

The only place where it matters is SD card (again, connected directly to microcontroller) which is never powered completely off.

In this condition I often see at boot:

```
[    4.679850] mmc0: card never left busy state
[    4.684203] mmc0: error -145 whilst initialising SD card
```

This is repeated four times in the boot-sequence and later SD devices (`/dev/mmcblk0*`) are unavailable.

Similar situation if I compile mmc drivers (`mtk_mmc.ko`, if it matters) and `modprobe mtk_mmc` later.

### Question:

Is there any command sequence I can send to MMC via *software*, before/during/after initialization sequence to completely reset it "as-if" power had been removed?

### Note:

This is particularly bad because (part of) my root filesystem is on that MMC card and thus any tweaking should be done in kernel/initrd.

If it matters: all MMC card are: "Transcend 8GB C10 MicroSD HC".

Comment: If you search for that error text in the kernel source, you would have discovered that it's the result of a failed command which should have been preceded by a software reset.  You are asking a XY question.  You don't seem to understand or state the X problem, yet assume issuing a software reset is the solution.   BTW just because MMC and SD cards use the same card connector does not mean they are equivalent.  MMC and SD cards have different standards issued by their respective organizations. "mmc" happens to be the name of the Linux device driver for both types of cards.

Comment: @sawdust: sorry, but I fail to understand You. IMHO problem happens in drivers/mmc/core/sd_ops.c:mmc_send_app_op_cond() which is called at the very beginning of drivers/mmc/core/sd.c:mmc_attach_sd() I *suppose* the problem is because mmc_send_app_op_cond()  expects card to be power-cycled, which is not the case (system works without problems if a true power-cycle is performed at reboot). Of course I don't fully understand, otherwise I wouldn't be asking for help. Can You, please, help me understand what is my missing "X problem"?

Comment: Okay, you found the relevant routine.  Now backtrack to the occasions where that routine is called.  Prior to each instance of calling that routine (I found two), **mmc_go_idle()** will be called, which does issue a software reset.  IOW the error message you are seeing is actually a report that the software reset (i.e. the idle command) never completed!  That is the X problem.  IMO I doubt that  issuing another software reset is the solution (unless there's somekind of timing issue).